# SVN/Tortoise SVN always use "theirs" when conflict occurs on a specific file

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

In one of our project the time had come and we needed to connect it to one of our another project through an interface. The interface dll is linked with the external property into the project and it's working very well. The problem is, that few of us need to work on both of the projects and thus this file is nearly always in conflict. Since it's just a binary it would be good to always resolve the conflict with the newest version(aka theirs). Is it possible, to do it jus for specific files?
I know, there is --accept "theirs-full" but it's for command line svn and it's not that automatic how I want it to be.

Comment: I'd like to know this too, did you figure anything out? To bad there are no answers even 2,5 years after asking..